# R, added line plot to barplot, the line points do not align to the x-axis evenly.

Tags: r, bar-chart, linechart

[image]

For the plot on **RIGHT**,  becuase the bar and line have same scale and limit, so I used the method as follow

(method 1):

```
mybar<-barplot(x,names.arg=1:10)      // create variable for plot
lines(mybar,y,type="o",pch=19,lwd=2)  // add line which points to x-axis
```

but for **LEFT** plot, the barplot data has limit (0,20000) and the lineplot data has limit (0,100000), I tried the above method, but it didn't work (it didn't give error, but the line didn't show). Then I tried the mothod as below

(method 2):

```
barplot(rbind(colum1,column2), names.arg=nameColumn,
        las=2, ylim=c(0,20000))
par(new = T)
plot(column3, axes = F, type="b",pch=20)
axis(4, at= ,labels= )
```

How do I centered the point to each bar for the **LEFT** plot? would method 1 solve the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

Firstly in the left plot, the values of line plot were incorrect. Method 1 would work (align the point to the bar), just need to scale the values of line plot.

```
plot(column3/5, axes = F, type="b",pch=20)
```

The reason of " it didn't give error, but the line didn't show" was because the left plot limit was set to (0, 20000), the values of line plot exceeded 20000 before scaling.

The plot after correction:
[image]

====== Update ======

This website gives me a lot helps for this solution: [www.cs.odu.edu](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~mweigle/cs795/mklein-IntroR/lecture/plotting.html)